# Injecting and using relay data from game ticks in JS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have been developing an overlay to sit over a game and have the data from that game displayed in the overlay. The relay is receiving the updates through JS and I can inject them directly into a div but I want to be able to corollate the value of a particular field to % of a bar progression (animation). I cannot figure out how to attach an animation which completion is dependant on a fluctuating variable.

The code for the relay in JS looks like this,

```
const WsSubscribers = {
  __subscribers: {},
  websocket: undefined,
  webSocketConnected: false,
  registerQueue: [],
  init: function (port, debug, debugFilters) {
    port = port || 49122;
    debug = debug || false;
    if (debug) {
      if (debugFilters !== undefined) {
        console.warn(
          "WebSocket Debug Mode enabled with filtering. Only events not in the filter list will be dumped"
        );
      } else {
        console.warn(
          "WebSocket Debug Mode enabled without filters applied. All events will be dumped to console"
        );
        console.warn(
          "To use filters, pass in an array of 'channel:event' strings to the second parameter of the init function"
        );
      }
    }
    WsSubscribers.webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:" + port);
    WsSubscribers.webSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
      let jEvent = JSON.parse(event.data);
      if (!jEvent.hasOwnProperty("event")) {
        return;
      }
      let eventSplit = jEvent.event.split(":");
      let channel = eventSplit[0];
      let event_event = eventSplit[1];
      if (debug) {
        if (!debugFilters) {
          console.log(channel, event_event, jEvent);
        } else if (debugFilters && debugFilters.indexOf(jEvent.event) < 0) {
          console.log(channel, event_event, jEvent);
        }
      }
      WsSubscribers.triggerSubscribers(channel, event_event, jEvent.data);
    };
    WsSubscribers.webSocket.onopen = function () {
      WsSubscribers.triggerSubscribers("ws", "open");
      WsSubscribers.webSocketConnected = true;
      WsSubscribers.registerQueue.forEach((r) => {
        WsSubscribers.send("wsRelay", "register", r);
      });
      WsSubscribers.registerQueue = [];
    };
    WsSubscribers.webSocket.onerror = function () {
      WsSubscribers.triggerSubscribers("ws", "error");
      WsSubscribers.webSocketConnected = false;
    };
    WsSubscribers.webSocket.onclose = function () {
      WsSubscribers.triggerSubscribers("ws", "close");
      WsSubscribers.webSocketConnected = false;
    };
  },
  /**
   * Add callbacks for when certain events are thrown
   * Execution is guaranteed to be in First In First Out order
   * @param channels
   * @param events
   * @param callback
   */
  subscribe: function (channels, events, callback) {
    if (typeof channels === "string") {
      let channel = channels;
      channels = [];
      channels.push(channel);
    }
    if (typeof events === "string") {
      let event = events;
      events = [];
      events.push(event);
    }
    channels.forEach(function (c) {
      events.forEach(function (e) {
        if (!WsSubscribers.__subscribers.hasOwnProperty(c)) {
          WsSubscribers.__subscribers[c] = {};
        }
        if (!WsSubscribers.__subscribers[c].hasOwnProperty(e)) {
          WsSubscribers.__subscribers[c][e] = [];
          if (WsSubscribers.webSocketConnected) {
            WsSubscribers.send("wsRelay", "register", `${c}:${e}`);
          } else {
            WsSubscribers.registerQueue.push(`${c}:${e}`);
          }
        }
        WsSubscribers.__subscribers[c][e].push(callback);
      });
    });
  },

  clearEventCallbacks: function (channel, event) {
    if (
      WsSubscribers.__subscribers.hasOwnProperty(channel) &&
      WsSubscribers.__subscribers[channel].hasOwnProperty(event)
    ) {
      WsSubscribers.__subscribers[channel] = {};
    }
  },

  triggerSubscribers: function (channel, event, data) {
    if (
      WsSubscribers.__subscribers.hasOwnProperty(channel) &&
      WsSubscribers.__subscribers[channel].hasOwnProperty(event)
    ) {
      WsSubscribers.__subscribers[channel][event].forEach(function (callback) {
        if (callback instanceof Function) {
          callback(data);
        }
      });
    }
  },

  send: function (channel, event, data) {
    if (typeof channel !== "string") {
      console.error("Channel must be a string");
      return;
    }
    if (typeof event !== "string") {
      console.error("Event must be a string");
      return;
    }
    if (channel === "local") {
      this.triggerSubscribers(channel, event, data);
    } else {
      let cEvent = channel + ":" + event;
      WsSubscribers.webSocket.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          event: cEvent,
          data: data,
        })
      );
    }
  },
};

//Time formatting for clock

function format(time) {
  // Hours, minutes and seconds
  var hrs = ~~(time / 3600);
  var mins = ~~((time % 3600) / 60);
  var secs = ~~time % 60;

  // Output like "1:01" or "4:03:59" or "123:03:59"
  var ret = "";
  if (hrs > 0) {
    ret += "" + hrs + ":" + (mins < 10 ? "0" : "");
  }
  ret += "" + mins + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "");
  ret += "" + secs;
  return ret;
}

//Initiation method for data

$(() => {
  WsSubscribers.init(49322, true);
  WsSubscribers.subscribe("game", "update_state", (d) => {
    let currentPlayerData = d["players"][d["game"]["target"]];

    //Data targeting JS

    $(".scoreboard .bluescore").text(d["game"]["teams"][0]["score"]);
    $(".scoreboard .orangescore").text(d["game"]["teams"][1]["score"]);
    $(".clockboard").text(format(d["game"]["time"]));
    $(".namedisplay").text(d["game"]["target"].slice(0, -2));
    $(".boostmeter").text(currentPlayerData.boost);
    $(".speedbar").text(currentPlayerData.speed);
    $(".savecount").text(currentPlayerData.saves);
    $(".goalcount").text(currentPlayerData.goals);
    $(".assistcount").text(currentPlayerData.assists);
    $(".shotcount").text(currentPlayerData.shots);
    $(".boostcount").text(currentPlayerData.boost);
  });
});
```

Essentially I want the `currentPlayerData.boost` to be relating to an animation which will be % completion 1:1 with this variable.

Is anyone familiar with JS/Animation who could help?

Thanks in advance